Replicating maven branch and release using Gradle
I'm moving from Maven to Gradle and have been happy so far. However, I'm stuck on the correct workflow to replicate maven branch and maven release.
My git workflow is setup like this:
The most recent SNAPSHOT code is on main, once we are at a point were we'd like to release we use mvn branch to create a "release" branch named something like release-2.0 (also we would set main to 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT). Then we put bug fixes, etc on that branch as needed and we use mvn release to tag and create releases on that branch as needed. etc.
I'm trying to use the nebula release plugin as a replacement and I think I have a handle around how it auto increments versions and creates tags, etc. But there is nothing documented about how to work on branches. This is my central problem.
It seems like maybe I need to manually create my branch and set a tag there (and on main) and then run my nebula release?
Any help would be appreciated.

maven branch? Does not exist? Where you using that? That might be the Maven Release Plugin which provides this functionality... Or you could use your CI/CD tools like Jenkins, whatever...

So, yes, I'm removing the pom and not using maven branch any longer.. What that did for me was determine the next version and create the branch name from that. I know I can write my own, I'm hoping that something in gradle land does it already
